# 10 ×10 multiplication table, but only shows those entries which are greater than a value entered by the user

Tags: java, multiplication

I have a 10x10 multiplication table. I need to code in so that when a user inputs a certain number, 50 for example, the numbers >50 are replaced by a character and the rest remain the same.

I know how to do this using strings but I have no clue how to do this in this situation. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class task4{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    int Multiples = 10;

    System.out.format("  Table");
    for(int z = 1; z<=Multiples;z++ ) {
    System.out.format("%5d",z);
}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for(int i = 1 ;i<=Multiples;i++) {
        System.out.format("%5d |",i);
        for(int j=1;j<=Multiples;j++) {
        System.out.format("%5d",i*j);
        }
        System.out.println();
          }
      }  
  }
```

Comment: Just as some coding advice, when creating variables their names should start with lower case letters. Having them start with capital letters makes it look like they are class names and makes it confusing to read

Comment: Also, Class name should start with an uppercase : task4 -> Task4

Comment: And it should be `String[] args`

Comment: Also, you should fix the indenting and can use `String... args` unless you're using a very old version of java.

Comment: Also, why do you have two Objects, both reading from `System.in`?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "My problems is im trying to make it so that the number he enters is replaced within the table by a character, in this case &&"...Do you mean table column and header values are replaced with "&&" instead of actual numbers?

From the code it looks like when you change Multiples2 it is never printed out anywhere, but of course the variable itself changes.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger.

Comment: I cleaned up the code for you here http://pastebin.mozilla.org/8544407. Here is also Java Coding Conventions from Oracle - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf. Every company can modify these a bit, but this is official one.

Comment: I am trying write a class which generates a 10 ×10 multiplication table, but only shows those entries which are greater than a value entered by the user. i have changed the question after noticing my mistakes and i appreciate the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be simple enough problem, basically you have table drawing code, your for loops, so we function that off into a nice little method public void drawTable(){} which we call to draw the table initially, but we also provide an overloaded version which takes a number public void drawTable(int maxDispNum){} and this method is the same except if i*j >maxDispNum we print a character instead. then in main we can simply while(true){ read val; drawTable(val);}

alternativley if you want to maintain a permanent record of what's been removed stored the table in an array, 10*10 in your case and use some marker, -1 works here to indicate removed, and simply check for that in your draw method,

Comment: Okay, i understand what you are saying but i have no clue how to put it into code.. I'll have an attempt tho, thank you.